# Synchronizer Log - Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

[image: Sync Issue]

Why is this happen to my Outlook. I tried many ways but still couldn't fix it. Every time I delete an email, it will show sync issue. My email is using IMAP/ SMTP, but I don't think its related. Anyone know how to fix it?

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that I'm using the wrong incoming/ outgoing mail server's, anyone who faced this problem please check your incoming and outgoing mail server first.

File -> Account Settings -> Server Settings -> Incoming Mail and Outgoing Mail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

According to my search, Outlook synchronization issues and errors occur when Outlook cannot establish a secure connection with the mailbox or synchronize mail items due to poor connectivity, lack of permissions, or damaged OST files.

From the error message in the Sync Issues folder you provided, seems that it is a problem of synchronize folders.

To resolve the Outlook synchronization log issues, check your network connection, sign in your account in the web to see if the issue exist.

Besides, try to create a New Outlook Profile.
Open Control Panel Mail > Show Profiles and then click Add.
Enter a profile name and click OK, then re-add your account.

Here is a link for your reference:https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/fix-outlook-synchronization-log-issues/

Comment: Do you think my reply is helpful? If so, please kindly mark it as answer.